# Find and Replace Mutli-line using regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, replace

So, I'm looking for a way to replace the entire instance of a `<data>` tag where the name contains '.Value'. I've whipped up a Regex for this (below), but it appears that VS2013 doesn't support multiline find/replace. **I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require third party downloads** (as this is for work).

Regex (works on http://www.regexr.com/):

```
  <data name=".*.Value" xml:space="preserve">\n    <value>.*</value>\n  </data>
```

Good (keep):

```
  <data name="ListItemResource12.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Test Value</value>
  </data>
```

Bad (replace):

```
  <data name="ListItemResource12.Value" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>123</value>
  </data>
```

If anyone has and ideas or tips toward multiline find/replace, they'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio does support multi-line regex search.

Your file probably uses `\r\n`; make sure your regex matches that.

Comment: Awesome, rigged up a new regex with this. Thanks a lot! 
Incase desired: "  <data name=".*.Value" xml:space="preserve">\r\n    <value>.*</value>\r\n  </data>"

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use regex for this kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), use an XML parser to change the values.

I'm a little rusty on my VS / C#, but using something like 
[an XMLParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
XMLParser(file.xml).findChildren("data").findChildren("value").setValue(123);
```

Comment: The OP's trying to perform a replacement *in the IDE itself*.

Comment: I don't know what kind of data the OP is working on, but if there are many files, and they're human-edited, then an XML parser would be the way to go instead of trying to handle every whitespace differentiation. A small program would be trivial to do so.